# Which IPs/hosts does Drupal query for updates?

Tags: 7, updating

I recently migrated a Drupal 7 installation from my own development server to a hosted solution, which runs all nice and dandy, however Drupal now can't load the data anymore to check for available updates.

It says,

> Fehler beim Abrufen der Daten über verfügbare Aktualisierungen.

Or in English, I think the translation is:

> No available update data

I asked the technical support of the web hoster if they could remove any kind of firewall or filter that'd block Drupal's external requests, and they replied to me that they needed to know which URLs / IPs or hosts are called so they could whitelist them.

What are these URLs?

Answer (score 5):

From `update.module`:

```
/**
 * URL to check for updates, if a given project doesn't define its own.
 */
define('UPDATE_DEFAULT_URL', 'http://updates.drupal.org/release-history');
```

Each module and theme is allowed to define it's own URL, it'll be in it's info file, but this one will cover most cases.

Note you need an access to all paths under this one, ie for Views updates Drupal will query http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/views/7.x

Comment: Alright, thank you! I'll contact them and see if that resolves the issue for most of the core plugins.

Comment: @slhck I would be grateful if you would either accept my answer if it works, or comment if it does not so I could improve it.

Comment: Your answer is great—I'm just still waiting for the web hoster to get back to me after I had them whitelist `updates.drupal.org` and found out that the updates still wouldn't work. Don't worry, I'll accept it once I can sort it out.

Comment: @slhck Oh my, there are hosting companies THAT slow?!